# Setting up React router: how to use {import} in the browser?

Tags: reactjs, import, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am following the [React-router docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/Introduction.md), but I have encountered an obstacle that is not really related to the router itself: Babel transpiles the {import} as `require`, which would be used by Express or Node.js on the server, but from what I understand from the docs, it is actually intended for client-side rendering.

Of course, the JSX file with the router transpiled using Babel and included into a HTML browser page does not work, since `require` is only used by express/node server-side.

May I ask how is it actually supposed to work in the browser?

Thank you

Comment: The browser currently doesn't support modules. Instead you use a module loader like webpack which can also run babel for you, will read all your import or require statements and spit out a single javascript file which the browser can read.

Comment: https://webpack.github.io/

Comment: you're 100% incorrect, azium.  look at the transpile.  babel's import shim does, in fact, rely on require.

Comment: @JohnHaugeland ah yes, my mistake.. anyway for the OP though, the point is the same.. it's not 'for node' so much as it is for something that bundle modules like webpack / browserify. Updating comment.

Comment: Babel changed it to : `var _reactRouter = require('react-router');` and so on. I thought I'd need to use something like webpack, I was just surprised that it apparently actually is impossible to use React router without "third-party" packages.

Comment: @user3104270 it is entirely possible to use React without using import/require or loading any modules, but most of the documentation you will see today uses them because production applications need that type of organization.

Comment: You're wrong again, azium.  `babel` is a third party package, and react has not been able to work without babel since 0.14.  Furthermore, since 15.0, react now relies in several niche cases on the `import`/`export` syntax, which in turn require a packager like `browserify`/`webpack`/`requirejs` unless run entirely serverside.  user3whatever is correct.

Comment: Yes, I know about React. I meant React-router specifically. Didn't find any examples that did not use Webpack etc.

Answer (score 1):

Babel's transpile of `import` produces code relying on CommonJS `require`, you're correct.

You're also correct that `node` offers a natire `require` implementation, whereas browsers do not.

There are tools - such as [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/), [browserify](https://browserify.org/), and [requirejs](https://requirejs.org/) (among others,) which each do at least two things:

1. to package up source into a single bundle
2. to expose that source in a way that satisfies `require` to match node, allowing you to use the same code at either side.

To that end, what you need to do is to pair `babel` with one of the packaging tools.

Webpack is more powerful; browserify is easier to use.

Here's a [tiny gulpfile](https://github.com/StoneCypher/pbar/blob/master/gulpfile.babel.js#L59) where I've automated the process.  The relevant source clip is this:

```
gulp.task('browserify', ['babel'], function() {

  var browserifyConfig = {}, 
      bpack            = browserify(browserifyConfig, { 'debug' : !production });

  return bpack
    .require('./dist/pbar.es5.js', { 'expose' : 'pbar' })
    .bundle()
    .on('error', errorHandler)
    .pipe(source('pbar.es5.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for commonjs like require statement to work in a browser environment. You will need to look into a bundling solution like:

https://webpack.github.io/
http://browserify.org/

A bundler will statically parse your commonjs files and their dependencies to create a bundle which can be used in the browser.

Internet is full of great examples on how they work.

Browserify is easier to get started than Webpack, however I would suggest you learn Webpack over Browserify. Webpack provides you much much more than just loading JS files with its extensive loaders, for example you can do something like:

`const imgSrc = require('images/test.svg')`

magical right?